# Htaccess 2 rewrite rules with post data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've a link goes to a file with GET parameters.

Link in href="" is:
http://www.aaa.com/part1/part2/part3/

My htaccess is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ detail.php?part1=$1&part2=$2&part3=$3 [L]
```

With this I get 3 data and show the URL as:
http://www.aaa.com/part1/part2/part3/

So far all works well. But i would like to change the URL but still get the GET values

The final result of URL should be:
http://www.aaa.com/part1-part2-text

I want to remove the / after part1 and part2 and remove part3 completly and put a text instead of part3.

I can rewrite the URL with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ part1=$1-part2=$2-text
```

but with this i'm not able to get the GET parameters.

Is there a way to combine these to rewrite parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) module first.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-text$ detail.php?part1=$1&part2=$2
```